# GitHub Desktop, Changing the path of my IDE

Tags: android-studio, path, ide, executable, github-desktop

So I'm Using GitHub Desktop right now and it works fine with VS code, but when i set my IDE to Android studio and hit "View in Android Studio" i get This ["Unable to find an executable for 'Android Studio' at (wrong path)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03Xuq.png) . The path that it looks at, is not where Android Studio is installed, i need to figure out how to change the path that it is looking for studio64.exe in.

When i tried hitting options it brought me here: [Options Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eArbH.png) but that was just the page where i changed my IDE, So i am a little dead in the water here, I'm not the savviest, but any idea is a good idea so if anyone knows a fix or workaround for this (or how to change the path it checks) it would be much appreciated! thanks!